# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}=$ ln$(\sqrt2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Question**: Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}=$ ln$(\sqrt2)$

**My attempt:**
I attempted a partial fractions decomposition of the general term and could not produce anything meaningful. I'm thinking log laws or the taylor series for ln$(x)$ might be useful here but I'm not sure what to do.

Would love if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} dx$$ for $|x|<1$

Comment: How does one get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}$? Is it partial fractions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have for $|x| <1$:

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^k}{k}$$

$$-\ln(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{x^k}{k}$$

so by summing:
$$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=2 x+0+2 \frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots=2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
i.e:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)$$
with $x=\frac{1}{3}$ you obtain:
$$\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{4\div 3}{2\div 3}}\right)=\ln(\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: If you wish, write **\boxed{...}** to box your expression inside, e.g. $\boxed{\ln (\sqrt 2)}$.

Comment: Awesome, I understand it all except for how to get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}$. Is it partial fractions?

Comment: @Sonjov It is not partial fraction, it is that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}$$ and when facing a sum looking like $$\sum a_n b^n$$ is it often a good idea to look at $$\sum a_n x^n$$ as a function of $x$.